# What is the proper way to start a container after it has exited?

Tags: docker, sql-server-2017

I have a container called sqlcontainer1.
The image is "microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest".
I restored a .bak file to it and now I can use it for local development.
And I can even see if from SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio).  Great!

The problem is after I reboot it the container status says "Exited".

The only way I can see to restart is to type:

```
docker start -ai sqlcontainer1
```

Then no command prompt is ever returned so I have to open another command prompt and retype:

```
docker ps -a
```

to see the status is now "UP 7 minutes".
OK, I'm glad it's up and I can now connect back with SSMS and work from there (although I am wondering why it says 7 minutes. I've only had it up seconds).
Good.

But there has to be a better way.
I just want two commands like this;

```
docker start containerName
docker stop containerName
```

Is there anything like this?

If I can get that far then I would like to look into a proper restart policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a container to restart=always when you create it or afterwards you can update it with

```
docker update --restart=always <container>
```

Then the container will always run on startup of your computer